Update a PlanGrid Text Annotation?
Is there a method or workaround to update a Text Annotation within the PlanGrid API?
It would come very handy to be able to control this important component.
import requests

url = "https://io.plangrid.com/projects/project_uid/annotations/annotation_uid"

payload = { "title": "Text String to be Inserted"
            "current_annotation": {
                        "color": "#FF0000"
            }
          }

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.plangrid+json; version=1",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.patch(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

